# Why AxesLabel disappear when the plots are combined?

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, labeling

I want to combine `plot1` and `plot2` and keep using the AxesLabel. But when they are combined by `Show[]`, the AxesLabel disappears. Why and how to fix it? Thanks.

```
plot1 = Graphics3D[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 0.7], Boxed -> False];
plot2 = SphericalPlot3D[
  1 + 2 Cos[2 \[Theta]], {\[Theta], 0, Pi}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 Pi}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
Show[plot1, plot2, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image]

Comment: try `Show[plot1, plot2, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]`, Alternatively, add the options `Axes -> True` and `AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}` to `Graphics3D` in `plot1 =Graphics3D[...]`, then use `Show[plot1,plot2]`

Comment: Thanks! `Axes -> True` works!

Comment: Show inherits the options of its first argument. In your case, the whole image will have only the options of plot1. If you want to see the options of plot2, change their places. That is, `Show[plot2, plot1, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]`